# Consuming deprecated soap versions in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, visual-studio-2015, wsdl

I need to consume a WSDL document. As of 2003, Microsoft suggested programs use SOAP 1.2.

Unfortunately, the megacorp hosting the data I need is still using SOAP 1.1.

This causes visual studio to crash when I try to parse the WSDL.

Is there a way to consume a WSDL 1.1 document using visual studio?

In addition to using Soap 1.1, note the following issues
 * The MIME types are wrong
 * The SSL cert is invalid
 * Some of the metadata doesn't follow standards

To be clear, I have no control over this WSDL. It is controlled by a Fortune 500 company. As of 2017, the latest version still does not use SOAP 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple problems that needed to be addressed

1. First, the port on the WSDL was hardcored to 80, even when going through SSL. The solution to this was to create the data contracts using http.
2. Once that was done, i needed to convert to SSL soap 1.1 (NOT 1.2). This can be done by adding  *security mode="Transport"*  to the basicHttpBinding.
3. Once this was done I needed to take care of the fact the SSl cert
   was invalid. This is a bit more in depth, but it the tldr is that it now routes to a server with a valid cert.